# Number theory problem on numbers II

Tags: elementary-number-theory

is n/m , n>m rational number?

like 7/2?

I want to know 7/2 is rational number or not

if it is not why and if it is why?

Comment: Yes: **every** real number that can be expressed as the quotient of two integers is by definition rational.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, that comment should have been submitted as an answer.

Jake Eum, assuming that n and m are or can be reduced to integer form, n/m is a rational number.

Comment: @DisplayName: Fair enough; I’ve made it one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: **every** real number that can be expressed as the quotient of two integers is by definition rational. The relative magnitudes of the two integers don’t matter: $\frac72$ is every bit as much a rational number in good standing as $\frac27$ is.

Comment: I recall that in school one would call the first improper fraction, and the latter proper. Wouldn't know if that is troubling the OP. We would also call $a/b$ where $b\mid a$ an "apparent" fraction.

Comment: @Pedro: The terms *proper* and *improper fraction* are pretty standard; I’ve not encountered *apparent fraction* before.

Answer (score 0):

A rational number is a number in the form $\dfrac{a}{b}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z},b\neq 0.$ That is, $a$ and $b$ must be integers, with $b$ being non-zero.

Some examples of rational numbers include:

$\dfrac{2}{7},\dfrac{7}{2},\dfrac{4}{7},\dfrac{2327}{2},-\dfrac{45}{4},-\dfrac{67}{70}.$

As you can see, the numbers can be positive or negative, as long as they are integers, with the denominator not $0$. It does not matter whether $a<b$ or if $a>b.$